# Как в диспетчере задач , сделать по нажатию кнопки - открытие файлового окна?

Tags: c#, файлы

Нужно чтоб в моем диспетчере задач, при нажатии на кнопку, открывалось файловое окно выбора (для запуска процесса), выбираю файл или что-то там и жму открыть = открывается файл и в диспетчере отображается этот запущенный процесс от файла. Вот кнопка, а что дальше?

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, я понял и сделал.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog a = new OpenFileDialog();
        a.ShowDialog();
        if (a.FileName == "")
            return;
        else
        {
            Process.Start(a.FileName);
        }



    }
```

Comment: `a.ShowDialog()` возвращает результат выбора, сравнивать имя файла с пустой строкой неверно.

Comment: Ну у меня все работает , открывается окно , выбираю файл - он открывается и запускается процесс. Что неверно?

Comment: Я же вам дал ссылку на MSDN там пример подробно расписан. Гляньте туда

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process MyProc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
MyProc.StartInfo.FileName = /*Имя Вашего файла*/;
MyProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
MyProc.Start();
```

и, видимо храним список процессов в листе, который и отображаем в Вашем диспетчере

P.S.: для открытия файла можно воспользоваться [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Не, тут что-то не так.
Как привязать это к кнопке то?
Я вставил, пишет  "System.InvalidOperationException не обработано"
Нужно чтоб открылось окно выбора файлов (вот когда картинку загружаешь куда-то например , такое же окно открывается) и я выбрал допустим документ .тхт и он открылся, и процесс его запустился

Comment: Это не сработает в таком виде, если выбран не исполняемый файл

Comment: А как тогда сделать то? Не пойму

Comment: @Grundy почему же? Сработает ассоциация файлов

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, да, действительно работает, почему-то думал есть разница между передачей имени файла: `Process.Start(fileName)` и вариантом в ответе